# Not able to find element for this DZNSegmentedControl view in Appium 1.6

Tags: appium-ios

I have been using **XCode 8** and **Appium 1.6** in **Mac OS X 10.11** for a while now. I have been using iOS-Appium inspector to find the elements using debug mode in **Intellij Idea**. But currently i am not able to find elements for the view that has been created using
[DZNSegmentedControl](http://DZNSegmentedControl) .

Comment: r u using appium inspector from appium lower version to identify the elements

Comment: Am using inspector from this site. 
https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector/blob/master/README.md
Let me know if there is any other better solution in using the inspector tool for iOS apps.
Thanks

Comment: you can use accessibility inspector from xcode.

Comment: Ya but it doesnt give you the xpath for an element.